# Aligning two Texts with images on one time. (ONE at left and other at right side) HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

See This Image:
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vJ0gTvs5Vko/UzvHazcJTsI/AAAAAAAAAmU/s8QLk-7iJ2Y/s1600/designername.png

There are two Text.
1) Powered by and a blogger sign
2) Designed by Designer Name

I want to place Powered by and blogger sign on left (It is on left)
and
I want to place the Designed by Designer name on right (It is also on left).

I want to place both of these on same line but one on left and other on right.

My Code:

CSS

```
 .creditfooter{
background: #333 url(http://nashwp.guuhuu.com/wp-content/themes/nash/assets/img/classy_fabric.png) repeat;
border-top:1px solid #222;
padding:20px;
color:#fff;
text-align:right;  font-family: 'Cabin';
margin-bottom:-5px;
}

.creditfooter a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:18px;
-webkit-transition: .3s color;
-moz-transition: .3s color;
-o-transition: .3s color;
-ms-transition: .3s color;
transition: .3s color;
}

.creditfooter a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color:#E47C14;
-webkit-transition: .3s color;
-moz-transition: .3s color;
-o-transition: .3s color;
-ms-transition: .3s color;
transition: .3s color;
}


.poweredbylinks {
text-align: left;
padding:20px;
border-bottom: -5px;

}

.poweredbylinks a{
text-decoration: none;
color:#ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
-webkit-transition: .3s color;
-moz-transition: .3s color;
-o-transition: .3s color;
-ms-transition: .3s color;
transition: .3s color;
}

.poweredbylinks a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color:#E47C14;
-webkit-transition: .3s color;
-moz-transition: .3s color;
-o-transition: .3s color;
-ms-transition: .3s color;
transition: .3s color;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class='creditfooter'>
<div class='poweredbylinks'>
  Powered By <span class='icon-blogger'></span> &amp; 
 <div class='creditfooterright'> Designed By   <a href='DESIGNER SITE' id='importantlinks'>DESIGNER NAME</a></div>
  </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please read first  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your CSS

```
.creditfooterright {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5X6n9/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css, allowing the Designed by to always stay on the right side:

```
.creditfooterright {
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood, can you not just use float:left on one image and float:right on the other. You may need to "clearfix" the parent container.

Comment: hmm, I've used float:right and it solved. I think no need of clear

Comment: Using the "clearfix" "hack" will give the parent element height, otherwise it will collapse it because floated elements are removed from the page flow (like absolutely positioned elements) and elements which come after it in the document will appear to sit on top instead of beneath it. This occurs in browsers which implement the box model properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
style="display: inline"
```

You can change with this code for your code

```
<div class='creditfooterright' style="display: inline"> Designed By   <a href='DESIGNER SITE' id='importantlinks'>DESIGNER NAME</a></div>
```

Comment: It will just display it on the same line, but won't align it to the right side, also using inline CSS for such things is quite bad.

Comment: If you do float: right, then your initial answer is useless.

Comment: May you describe again ?

Comment: There is no need to do `display: inline` if you're doing `float: right`, as it will move it do the same line automatically. You also shouldn't hard code your CSS on your DOM elements, e.g. `<div style="...">`, as in case if that code will have to be reused somewhere, and at some point you will decide to make some changes it will take you years to amend all files, where if you do it in external CSS file, it will be 100 times easier.